# Owin get query string parameters

Tags: .net, owin, katana

I am trying to get query string parameters from Owin request. Get operation for parameter 'test' remains empty, although this parameter was in query string. How can I read request parameter from OWIN host?

Call:

```
localhost:5000/?test=firsttest
```

Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHandlerAsync((req, res) =>
        {
            string paramTest = req.Get<string>("test");                             
            return res.WriteAsync(paramTest);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Get<T>` looks in the OWIN environment dictionary for any key. The individual GET request parameters aren't part of that dictionary though. You could get the complete query string using `req.QueryString` which is equivalent to `req.Get<string>("owin.RequestQueryString")` and returns `test=firsttest` in your case. That could be easily parsed.

Another option would be something like this:

```
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            var param = ctx.Request.Query.Get("test");
            await next();
        });
```

`IOwinRequest` implementations provide you with a parsed query string. Note that the object one gets from `IOwinContext.Request` implements `IOwinRequest` while the object that is passed to `UseHandlerAsync` is of a completely different type (`Owin.Types.OwinRequest`) which neither provides the context nor the parsed query string (afaik).

Answer (score 2):

Had the same question, here's my solution.

The ApiController that serves as a base class for specific controllers as in this very simple example ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api ) has a property this.Request.RequestUri.Query which contains the query string.